# get stored xml code from MySql in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml

I store my xml code in MySql DB as longtext. I just want to print out the xml code as it is to screen. Only var_dump() worked but it displays string ' output ' text length. I dont want string and textlength
My Code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT xmlData, date, time FROM table order by idtable desc limit 0,1';
mysql_select_db('db');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM))
{

//attempt 1
/*ob_start();
var_dump($row[0]);
$result = ob_get_clean();
echo $result; */

//attempt 2
//var_export($row[0], true);

//attempt 3
//$dump = print_r($row[0], true);
//$dump = var_export($row[0], true);

//attempt 4
//nl2br($row[0]);

//attempt 5
//$wordParLine = 10;
//wordwrap('$row[0]', $wordParLine);

//attempt 6
$var1 =$row[0]; 
$new = substr($var1,0,2170); 
}
```

Comment: Just a note, It'll be best to use `htmlspecialchars( xml )` and having a mysql data field of `BLOB` to store `XML`; this'll safely escape quotes and be of a large file size capacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why aren't you just printing it out, using a function like `echo`?

Problem with the xml is, that it is displayed in your browser as is, so you won't see anything. You can counter this using by encoding the xml string, using a function like [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

For example:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM))
{
    echo htmlentities($row[0]);
}
```

If this doesn't solve your question, could you please provide some test data?